# How to use curl get image right filename and extension

Tags: bash, shell, curl, command

My links just like below

```
https://cdn.sspai.com/2022/06/22/article/a88df95f3401d5b6c9d716bf31eeef33?imageView2/2/w/1120/q/90/interlace/1/ignore-error/1
```

If I use chrome to open this like and `cmd + s`
I will get the right filename and right extension `png`.

But if I use bash below, then it will no extension:

```
curl -J -O https://cdn.sspai.com/2022/06/22/article/a88df95f3401d5b6c9d716bf31eeef33?imageView2/2/w/1120/q/90/interlace/1/ignore-error/1
```

I just want to download image with right filename and extension.

```
a88df95f3401d5b6c9d716bf31eeef33.png
```

Same error include different image links below:

```
https://cdn.sspai.com/article/fa848601-4cdf-38b0-b020-7afd6efc4a7e.jpg?imageMogr2/auto-orient/quality/95/thumbnail/!800x400r/gravity/Center/crop/800x400/interlace/1
```

Comment: You should probably tag this with chrome so someone who knows chrome can tell you whatever magic chrome uses to get the extension and then maybe you could implement that in shell.

Comment: In the output header (with `curl -I <url>`) you can see `Content-Type: image/png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name from the URL itself.

```
url="YOUR-URL"
file="`echo "${url}" | sed 's|\?.*|.jpg|' | xargs basename`"
curl -o "${file}.tmp" "${url}"
mv "${file}.tmp" "${file}"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this way not perfect. 
because the file not just format named jpg. 
it can be png and more

Comment: You can get one correct suffix for a file with "file" utility.
file -b --extension YOUR-FILE | cut -d / -f 1

Comment: some url just didn't provide .  and extension

Comment: That's where "file" utility comes in. It doesn't use the filename to calculate the extension, it doesn't need the file to end with  ". and extension", it analyzes the file's content and gives you it's file format.